# Play sound on setInterval

Tags: javascript, audio, random, mp3, setinterval

Im trying to display an image, play a random sound and display a random name by a random time. Everything works but the sound. It only plays sometimes.. I have no idea on how to fix it - Maybe another way to play the sound of some sort. Got any suggestions?

```js
document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';

var mytime = new Array("12000", "22000");
var randomtime = mytime[Math.floor(Math.random() * mytime.length)];

window.setInterval(function(){
    /// call your function here

    //WORKS
    document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'block';

    var myarray = new Array("Camilla", "Charlotte", "Beata", "Katrine", "Peppe", "Vorre", "Rene", "Schmidt", "Søholm", "Uffe", "Kromann");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;

    var collection=[];// final collection of sounds to play
    var loadedIndex=0;// horrible way of forcing a load of audio sounds

    function init(audios) {
        for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
            var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
            collection.push(audio);
            buffer(audio);
        }
    }

    function buffer(audio) {
        if(audio.readyState==4)
            return loaded();
        setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
    }

    function loaded() {
        loadedIndex++;
        if(collection.length==loadedIndex)
            playLooped();
    }

    function playLooped() {
        var audio=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
        audio=collection[audio];
        audio.play();
    }

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME";
        document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';
    }, 10000);

    init([
        'sound/camel1.mp3',
        'sound/camel2.mp3',
        'sound/camel3.mp3'
    ]);
},randomtime);
```

```html
 <img id="myimage" src="dist/images/giphy.gif" width="420" height="236" />
 <h1 id="message">THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME</h1>
```

Comment: Check browser console for unhandled promise rejections. Also, consider using indentation while writing code, else it's quite difficult to read.

Comment: @CertainPerformance HTML added and no errors in the console

Comment: I don't know what "THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME" is, but I'm excited.

Answer (score 0):

With your permission I organized a bit the code.(Just a bit) I try to make sure when all audio files are ready to play then to start the "loop". The callback for each audio.oncanplay is incrementing the total nr of loaded audio files in collection. When this nr is equal to total number of audiotracks in collection we call the loop.

```js
var nrReadyToPlay = 0;
var collection = [];
var soundtracks = [
  'sound/camel1.mp3',
  'sound/camel2.mp3',
  'sound/camel3.mp3'
];

function audioReady() {
  nrReadyToPlay++;
  // When nr of ready callbacks calls will be equal to the nr of soundtracks then start loop.
  if (nrReadyToPlay !== soundtracks.length) return;
  startLoop()
}

function init(audios) {
  for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    audio.oncanplay = audioReady;
    audio.muted = true;
    collection.push(audio);
  }
}
// returns a random name
function setRandomMessage() {
  var myarray = ["Camilla", "Charlotte", "Beata", "Katrine", "Peppe", "Vorre", "Rene", "Schmidt", "Søholm", "Uffe", "Kromann"];
  var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
}
// plays a random audio file
function playRandomAudio() {
  var audio = collection[Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length))];
  audio.muted = false;
  if (audio.readyState !== 4) console.log('ERROR')
  audio.play();
}

function displayImage() {
  document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'block';
}

function startLoop() {
  document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';

  var mytime = [10000, 12000];
  var randomtime = mytime[Math.floor(Math.random() * mytime.length)];

  window.setInterval(function() {
    displayImage();
    setRandomMessage()
    playRandomAudio();
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>My title</title>
        </head>
        <body>

          <image id="myimage" src="pen.jpg"></image>
          <h1 id="message">THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME</h1>


          <script>
            var nrReadyToPlay = 0;
            var collection = [];
            var soundtracks = [
              'sound/camel1.mp3',
              'sound/camel2.mp3',
              'sound/camel3.mp3'
            ];

            function audioReady() {
              nrReadyToPlay++;
              // When nr of ready callbacks calls will be equal to the nr of soundtracks then start loop.
              if (nrReadyToPlay !== soundtracks.length) return;
              startLoop()
            }

            function init(audios) {
              for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
                var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
                audio.oncanplay = audioReady;
                audio.muted = true;
                collection.push(audio);
              }
            }
            // returns a random name
            function setRandomMessage() {
              var myarray = ["Camilla", "Charlotte", "Beata", "Katrine", "Peppe", "Vorre", "Rene", "Schmidt", "Søholm", "Uffe", "Kromann"];
              var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
              document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
            }
            // plays a random audio file
            function playRandomAudio() {
              var audio = collection[Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length))];
              audio.muted = false;
              if (audio.readyState !== 4) console.log('ERROR')
              audio.play();
            }

            function displayImage() {
              document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'block';
            }

            function startLoop() {
              document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';
            
              var mytime = [3000, 5000];
              var randomtime = mytime[Math.floor(Math.random() * mytime.length)];
            
              window.setInterval(function() {
                displayImage();
                setRandomMessage()
                playRandomAudio(); 
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME";
                    document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = 'none';
                }, 10000);     
              }, randomtime);
            }


            init(soundtracks);

            </script>

        </body>
      </html>

  }, randomtime);
}

init(soundtracks);
```

```html
 <img id="myimage" src="dist/images/giphy.gif" width="420" height="236" />
<h1 id="message">THE-CAMEL-YELLING-DRINKING-GAME</h1>
```

Comment: Still doesn't play the sound, well only sometimes :s In the original code the image were displayed in 10 seconds and the disappeared before looping again.

Comment: First of all I've run it locally and can assure that it works, secondly you must interact with the page, (Ex: make a click, move mouse) otherwise browser will not play any media. Btw, I added "disappeared before looping again"